# VBA - Excel - Search multiple string through multiple files in a folder

Tags: vba, excel

I begin with VBA and programmation.

I have a spreadsheet with X values. Each of this values match (or not) with an .xml file in a folder (the value is present in the xml title).
What I need is that for each of these values my program search a matching .xml file and write "found" or "not found" next to the value in the spreadsheet.

My code so far :

```
Sub StringExistsInFile()
Dim theString As String
Dim path As String
Dim StrFile As String
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim file As TextStream
Dim line As String

theString = Sheets("PHILA_RESULT_PART_201703210429").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
path = "C:\Users\Jira\Desktop\LaPoste\20170324_120939_export_phila_commande.Envoi1\"
StrFile = Dir(path & "*.xml")
i = 1

Do While StrFile <> ""

    Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(path & StrFile)
    Do While Not file.AtEndOfLine
        line = file.ReadLine
        If InStr(1, line, theString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Sheets("PHILA_RESULT_PART_201703210429").Cells(i + 1, 14).Value = "found"
            i = i + 1
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    file.Close
    Set file = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    StrFile = Dir()

Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help.

How the value are store in the spreadsheet :

[spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjbrL.png)

In blue = the values I search.
In red = where I want to write "found" or "not found".

Edit :

And there is my code after some "improvments"

```
Sub StringExistsInFile()
Dim theString As String
Dim path As String
Dim StrFile As String
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim file As TextStream
Dim line As String

theString = Sheets("PHILA_RESULT_PART_201703210429").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
path = "C:\Users\Jira\Desktop\LaPoste\20170324_120939_export_phila_commande.Envoi1\"
StrFile = Dir(path & "*.xml")
i = 1

Do While Sheets("PHILA_RESULT_PART_201703210429").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> ""

    Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(path & StrFile)
    Do While Not file.AtEndOfLine
        line = file.ReadLine
        If InStr(1, line, theString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Sheets("PHILA_RESULT_PART_201703210429").Cells(i + 1, 14).Value = "found"
        Else
            Sheets("PHILA_RESULT_PART_201703210429").Cells(i + 1, 14).Value = "not found"
        End If
    Loop
    i = i + 1

    file.Close
    Set file = Nothing
    StrFile = Dir()

Loop
```

Set fso = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: what's your issue? BTW move that `Set fso = Nothing` right before `End Sub`

Comment: Hi. My issue is that it's writing 74 times (there is 74 files in my folder) "found" in the column "N". So I guess the treatment is correct but not the way I am writing the results.

If I recap my need : I search if the value in "B2" is present in one of my .xml file, if yes I write "found" in "N2", in not I write "not found" in "N2". And I do this for each row of my spreadsheet if "BX" <> "".

Comment: and what are the expected results?

Comment: If an xml file is matching the value in "B2", I write "found" in "N2", if there is not match I write "not found". I do this for each row of my spreadsheet.

Comment: and why 74 "found" are not good?

Comment: Because there are 18 values in the column B and that there is only 1 file per value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a logic flaw: as long as current open file current line matches `theString`, your `Exit Do` stops reading that file but you then keep checking other files and updating row index

I'd propose you the following (commented) refactoring of your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub StringsExistInFiles()
    Dim path As String
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim filesPath As Variant
    Dim cell As Range

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    path = "C:\Users\Jira\Desktop\LaPoste\20170324_120939_export_phila_commande.Envoi1\"

    If Not GetFilesWithGivenExtension(fso, path, "xml", filesPath) Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if no files with given extension in given path

    With Sheets("PHILA_RESULT_PART_201703210429") '<--| reference your sheet
        For Each cell In .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp)) '<--| loop through its column "B" cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
            StringExistsInFiles fso, filesPath, cell '<--| check all files for the exitence of the current cell content and write the result in corresponding column N cell
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub StringExistsInFiles(fso As FileSystemObject, filesPath As Variant, cell As Range)
    Dim line As String
    Dim filePath As Variant
    Dim found As Boolean

    With fso '<--| reference passed FileSystemObject
        For Each filePath In filesPath '<--| loop through all passed paths
            With .OpenTextFile(filePath) '<--| reference current path file
                Do While Not .AtEndOfLine '<--| loop until referenced file last line
                    line = .ReadLine '<--| read referenced file current line
                    If InStr(1, line, cell.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then '<--| if passed string is found in referenced file current line
                        found = True '<--| mark you made it
                        Exit Do '<--| stop reading referenced file further lines
                    End If
                Loop
                .Close '<--| close referenced file
                If found Then Exit For '<--| if you made it then stop reading further files
            End With
        Next
        cell.Offset(, 12).Value = IIf(found, "found", "not found")
    End With
End Sub


Function GetFilesWithGivenExtension(fso As FileSystemObject, folderToSearch As String, extensionToFind As String, files As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim fsoFile As file
    Dim nFiles As Long

    With fso.GetFolder(folderToSearch) '<--| reference passed folder
        ReDim files(1 To .files.count) '<--| size paths array to the number of files in referenced folder
        For Each fsoFile In .files '<--| loop through referenced folder files
            If fso.GetExtensionName(fsoFile) = extensionToFind Then '<--| if current file extension matches passed one
                nFiles = nFiles + 1 '<--| update valid files counter
                files(nFiles) = fsoFile.path '<--| store current valid file path in paths array
            End If
        Next
    End With
    If nFiles > 0 Then '<--| if any valid file found
        ReDim Preserve files(1 To nFiles) '<--| resize paths array correspondingly
        GetFilesWithGivenExtension = True '<--| return successful result
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it is working as intended. Now I have to understand everything :)