# How to search for a string of list in from multiple text files

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and need help. I have a list in excel col A and a lot of text files in a folder and want search each item in the excel list through the txt files and if there is a hit it in any of the txt file it returns 'True' and move to next string to complete.
Any help will be grateful

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what specific problems did you run into?  Questions with no code tend to get closed  - it's best to include your efforts along with a description of any errors etc.  Please review [ask]

Comment: Thank you Tim, and my apologies, i really don't know where to begin, I am used to recording macros from  using the built in macro recorder. This is one task where i can't user the recorder to solve the problem

Comment: I think i found a link the could point me to the right direction
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015351/vba-excel-search-multiple-string-through-multiple-files-in-a-folder
I am going to put my thinking cap on to adapt to my problem.

Comment: That looks like a good place to start.